# Get value from v-item-group

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following v-item-group where a user can select a pre-defined amount or type himself a custom amount.

Here's the design of the v-item-group. However, I can't figure out how to get the value from Custom Amount. The property this.item is undefined. I thought I need to create another v-model but perhaps there is a simple and straignt-forward solution.

[image: That's how v-item-group looks like]

```
        <v-item-group v-model="item">
          <v-container>
            <v-row>
              <v-item v-for="n in amounts" :key="n" v-slot="{ active, toggle }">
                <v-card
                  :color="active ? 'deep-purple accent-3' : 'grey'"
                  class="d-flex align-center rounded-circle mr-3"
                  dark
                  height="64"
                  width="64"
                  @click="toggle"
                >
                  <v-scroll-y-transition>
                    <div v-if="active" class="h3 flex-grow-1 text-center">
                      {{ n }}
                    </div>
                    <div v-else class=" h5 flex-grow-1 text-center">
                      {{ n }}
                    </div>
                  </v-scroll-y-transition>
                </v-card>
              </v-item>
              <v-item v-slot="{ toggle }" key="5">
                <v-text-field
                  label="Custom Amount"
                  hide-details="auto"
                  @click="toggle"
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-item>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>
        </v-item-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a local `data` property, and use [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) on `v-text-field`:

```html
<v-text-field v-model="customAmount">
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      customAmount: '2000'
    }
  }
}
```

The function that processes the user's selection could then get the custom value simply by `this.customAmount`.

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/oNYOxQr?editors=1010)